# How to convert a C# string to javascript string?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

When I serialize my C# list to a JSON string, I can't get my javascript code to recognize it as a string.

in my Default.aspx.cs :

```
private string allDataJSON;
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
allDataJSON = ser.Serialize(new AccessAllData().getAllData());
```

in my javascript file:

```
var allDataJSON = <% =this.allDataJSON %>;
var myHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
myHeading.innerHTML = allDataJSON;
```

As it is, the first line in my javascript file gives me an error which says unexpected < symbol.... but I saw other answers here giving this syntax but they were 3-4 years old.

All I want here is for my h1 text to be the same as the one in the allDataJSON string.

Comment: Where does it give error? on server side or on client side?

Comment: I've tried many different syntaxes. this is the exact error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put ASP.NET code in javascript files. You'd want to do something like this:

```
//In your .aspx page, before you load your javascript file
<script>var allDataJSON = <% =this.alllDataJSON %></script>
```

And then just reference `allDataJSON` in your javascript file

Comment: that helps, but I still get a syntax error with that line of code in visual studio, right between = and <

Comment: Thanks!! all that is left for that line of code to work is a single quote on each side of  <% =this.alllDataJSON %>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var allDataJSON = '<% =this.allDataJSON %>';
```

Since that variable is a string, it needs proper delimiters.

EDIT: Also, you must either include the code in the .aspx file or modify your configuration so that the .js files also pass through the ASP.NET pipeline (which I don't recommend).